# RavenDB UpdateByIndex using a map/reduce index on a denormalized collection

Tags: ravendb, patch

I have a document that contains a denormalized collection, I have created a map/reduce index that returns the indivdual items from the collection. Is it possible to use this index to update the denormalized data? I have attempted to but the data isn't updated. There are no errors that occur, my patch just executes silenty. I am able to update the denormalized collection using a map only index on the whole document, however I want to use the map/reduce index so I can query specific items to update from the denomalized collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution you need for this:

http://ayende.com/blog/162340/ravens-scripted-index-results

Comment: In the context of running UpdateByIndex as part of a (one-time) migration you should be aware that the presented solution will re-run on each indexing attempt. So to run this as a migration, you'd put a temporary index like this.